# How can I use the sql case clause in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, hql, case

I really need help regarding this one.

Here is the code snippet:

```
  hSql=" select case 
      when min(start_day_plan) is not NULL then min(start_day_plan)
      else to_date((min(insertDate)) - cast('1 month' as interval),'yyyy-MM-dd' )
      end 
      from Project"

    getHibernateTemplate().find(hSql);
```

But this generates the error below:

---

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.CaseNode 
 \-[CASE] CaseNode: 'case'
    +-[WHEN] SqlNode: 'when'
    |  +-[IS_NOT_NULL] UnaryLogicOperatorNode: 'is not null'
    |  |  \-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'min'
    |  |     \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'start_day_plan' {originalText=start_day_plan}
    |  \-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'min'
    |     \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'start_day_plan' {originalText=start_day_plan}
    \-[ELSE] SqlNode: 'else'
       \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
          +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'to_date' {originalText=to_date}
          \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
             +-[MINUS] BinaryArithmeticOperatorNode: '-' {dataType=org.hibernate.type.DoubleType@bb21ab}
             |  +-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'min'
             |  |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'insertDate' {originalText=insertDate}
             |  \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
             |     +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'cast' {originalText=cast}
             |     \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
             |        +-[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: ''1 month''
             |        \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'interval' {originalText=interval}
             \-[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: ''yyyy-MM-dd''
```

what will be the correct query for this? im just trying to subtract 1 month from the insertdate.

If you could help, please do so..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I stumble upon this same problem recently. My error came from the fact JPA expects the same fields name in the query **AND** in the entity class.

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
  private String field1;
  ...
}
```

In the query `field1` is expected and not `Field1` nor `FIELD1` and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solution than [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6073522/1267100).  We use JPA annotations on the getter but the field name was starting with a capital (which is not a good practice anyway).

```
private Timestamp MyTime;
...
@Column(name = "MYTIME")
public Timestamp getMyTime() {
    return MyTime;
}
```

I think when Hibernate was resolving my field name based on the getter it was looking for a field named `myTime` but there was only `MyTime`.  The problem was solved when I renamed the field with the correct camel case convention (`myTime`)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your forgot the table you want to query.

```
     select 
       case 
         when min(start_day_plan) is not NULL then min(start_day_plan) 
         else to_date((min(insertDate)) - cast('1 month' as interval),'yyyy-MM-dd' ) 
       end
     from MyTable
```

Comment: ooppss... i just forgot to paste it here... :)

Comment: do i need to to import classes for this or case is not supported in hql?

Comment: **case** is perfectly supported in hql (if the underlying database supports it).

Comment: but what's this 
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.CaseNode 
all about? what is wrong with the code?

Comment: @side_dish I don't know for sure. I suggest uou try to make the simplest request to work, then add complexity little by little, until you encouter the error. Then, either you find the correction, or you ask us a more focused question with the simplest case that is wrong, stating what works and what doesn't ...